# php file for portfolio get the wrong return?

Tags: php

I'm not so good on php and I have bought revelation theme and get a error code for both portfolio (the one column galleri is working but not the two or three columns) and galleri, seems to be the same problem and can't get support from theme see the following link and attached file

http://anweb-design.se/marco/?page_id=74

Very thankful for some help, thanks

Here is the **theme-thumbnails-resize.php**

```
<?php

/*

 * Resize images dynamically using wp built in functions

 * Victor Teixeira

 *

 * php 5.2+

 *

 * Exemplo de uso:

 * 

 * <?php 

 * $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 

 * $image = vt_resize( $thumb, '', 140, 110, true );

 * ?>

 * <img src="<?php echo $image[url]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image[width]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image[height]; ?>" />

 *

 * @param int $attach_id

 * @param string $img_url

 * @param int $width

 * @param int $height

 * @param bool $crop

 * @return array

 */

function celta_resize( $attach_id = null, $img_url = null, $width, $height, $crop = false ) {



    // this is an attachment, so we have the ID

    if ( $attach_id ) {



        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach_id, 'full' );

        $file_path = get_attached_file( $attach_id );



    // this is not an attachment, let's use the image url

    } else if ( $img_url ) {



        $file_path = parse_url( $img_url );

        $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file_path['path'];



        //$file_path = ltrim( $file_path['path'], '/' );

        //$file_path = rtrim( ABSPATH, '/' ).$file_path['path'];



        $orig_size = getimagesize( $file_path );



        $image_src[0] = $img_url;

        $image_src[1] = $orig_size[0];

        $image_src[2] = $orig_size[1];

    }



    $file_info = pathinfo( $file_path );

    $extension = '.'. $file_info['extension'];



    // the image path without the extension

    $no_ext_path = $file_info['dirname'].'/'.$file_info['filename'];



    $cropped_img_path = $no_ext_path.'-'.$width.'x'.$height.$extension;



    // checking if the file size is larger than the target size

    // if it is smaller or the same size, stop right here and return

    if ( $image_src[1] > $width || $image_src[2] > $height ) {



        // the file is larger, check if the resized version already exists (for $crop = true but will also work for $crop = false if the sizes match)

        if ( file_exists( $cropped_img_path ) ) {



            $cropped_img_url = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $cropped_img_path ), $image_src[0] );



            $vt_image = array (

                'url' => $cropped_img_url,

                'width' => $width,

                'height' => $height

            );



            return $vt_image;

        }



        // $crop = false

        if ( $crop == false ) {



            // calculate the size proportionaly

            $proportional_size = wp_constrain_dimensions( $image_src[1], $image_src[2], $width, $height );

            $resized_img_path = $no_ext_path.'-'.$proportional_size[0].'x'.$proportional_size[1].$extension;            



            // checking if the file already exists

            if ( file_exists( $resized_img_path ) ) {



                $resized_img_url = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $resized_img_path ), $image_src[0] );



                $vt_image = array (

                    'url' => $resized_img_url,

                    'width' => $proportional_size[0],

                    'height' => $proportional_size[1]

                );



                return $vt_image;

            }

        }



        // no cache files - let's finally resize it

        $new_img_path = image_resize( $file_path, $width, $height, $crop );

        $new_img_size = getimagesize( $new_img_path );

        $new_img = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $new_img_path ), $image_src[0] );



        // resized output

        $vt_image = array (

            'url' => $new_img,

            'width' => $new_img_size[0],

            'height' => $new_img_size[1]

        );



        return $vt_image;

    }



    // default output - without resizing

    $vt_image = array (

        'url' => $image_src[0],

        'width' => $image_src[1],

        'height' => $image_src[2]

    );



    return $vt_image;

}

?>
```

Comment: Where is hte error code you say you get. Can't see anything obviously wrong to help you with. Might help if you put error in the question.